# How do I create this complicated table in latex?

Tags: tables

[image: This table has some merged rows and columns]

How do I create it? Also how to add some colors to the cells? I have uploaded the image in wrong orientation. Please correct it and help me. Thank you.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far ... MWE?

Comment: I have no idea how to begin this kind of table. I am a beginner. So I am hoping to find some help around here.

Comment: to start with, you could have a look at `\multicolumn` and/or the `multirow` package

Comment: Hi Soumya, if you're just starting out with LaTeX and tables, take a look at the [LaTeX wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables). Here on TeX Stackexchange we can always help you, but broad questions such as how to make a table are better answered elsewhere.

Comment: Have you seen question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211273/how-to-create-a-complicated-table-in-latex?rq=1?  That coud be a duplicate for your question, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>This becomes my obligation :-)</sub>

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  %% for colors
\usepackage{multirow}  %% for \multirow
\usepackage{hhline}  %% for hhline gives better \cline while coloring
\usepackage{graphicx}  %% for \rotatebox
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}

\begin{document}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!40}{gray!40}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
%\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\begin{tabular}{|C|>{\columncolor{gray!40}}C|*{5}{C|}}\hhline{*{7}{-}}
   \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!40}}& \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\cellcolor{white}Group III} \\\hhline{~~*{5}{-}}
   \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{III--V} & 5 & 13 & 31 & 69 & 81 \\
   \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Compounds} & B & Al & Ga & XX & XX \\\hhline{*{7}{-}}
   \hiderowcolors
   &  7 & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
   &  XX &  &  & XX &  & \\\hhline{~*{6}{-}}
   &  7 & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
   &  XX &  & XX & XX & XX & \\\hhline{~*{6}{-}}
   &  7 & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
   &  XX &  &  & XX &  & \\\hhline{~*{6}{-}}
   &  7 & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
   &  XX &  &  & XX &  & \\\hhline{~*{6}{-}}
   &  7 & XX & XX & XX & XX & XX \\
\multirow{-10}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Group V}}
   &  XX &  &  & XX &  & \\\hhline{*{7}{-}}
\multicolumn{4}{|p{\dimexpr4cm+6\tabcolsep+3\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{\cellcolor{gray!40} Some thing you put here} &
\multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr3cm+4\tabcolsep+2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|}{\cellcolor{gray!40} Some thing you put here Some thing you put here}\\\hhline{*{7}{-}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]